# ColdFusion9 UDF nested invoke

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a cfm file that is created in CF9. It has 7 `<cfinvoke>` statements all being the same except for the `method` and `returnvariable`. Is there a way to put this into a function or loop that would shorten my code and still work?

Example:

```
<cfsilent>
<cfinvoke component="financial.financial" method="getExecSummary" returnvariable="qExecSummary">
    <cfinvokeargument name="level" value="#URL.level#" />
    <cfinvokeargument name="stateGM" value="#URL.stateGM#" />
</cfinvoke>
<!---Added this to test if I can get more than one sheet to the Workbook--->
<cfinvoke component="financial.financial" method="getExecSummary331" returnvariable="qExecSummary331">
    <cfinvokeargument name="level" value="#URL.level#" />
    <cfinvokeargument name="stateGM" value="#URL.stateGM#" />
</cfinvoke>
</cfsilent>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<cffunction name="getSummary" output=true>
    <cfargument name="method" required="true">
    <cfargument name="returnvariable" required="true">
    <cfargument name="level" required="true">
    <cfargument name="stateGM" required="true">

    <cfinvoke component="financial.financial" method="#method#" returnvariable="#returnvariable#">
        <cfinvokeargument name="level" value="#level#" />
        <cfinvokeargument name="stateGM" value="#stateGM#" />
    </cfinvoke>

    <cfreturn #returnvariable#> 
</cffunction>


<cfset getSummary("getExecSummary","qExecSummary","#URL.level#","#URL.stateGM#")>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction? If this is even possible. I've been trying to find information on doing this, but I don't see anything yet.

I've read through [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0999c-7ff5.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0999c-7ff3) and [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff3.html) looking for help. I've also found several posts that didn't help either.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but setting `output="false"` for the component/function should get rid of any extra white space so you no longer need `cfsilent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simpler to use [createObject("component")](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-697b.html), than `cfinvoke`. Just create an instance of the component. Then invoke the proper method and capture the result in the desired variable:

```
<!--- separated calls for readability -->
<cfset comp = createObject("component", "path.to.YourComponent")>
<cfset result = comp.firstMethod( "value1", "value2")>
```

*IF* the methods are all stateless (and properly scoped) you could simply reuse the same instance for all of the method calls:

```
<cfset comp = createObject("component", "path.to.YourComponent")>
<cfset result1 = comp.firstMethod( "value1", "value2" )>
<cfset result2 = comp.secondMethod( "value1", "value2" )>
<cfset result3 = comp.thirdMethod( "value1", "value2" )>
```

Also, as John Wish [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151353/coldfusion9-udf-nested-invoke/38151699?noredirect=1#comment63734691_38151699):

> In CF9+ you can also use the `new` operator if you prefer like so:
>
> ```
> <cfset comp = new path.to.YourComponent()>
> ```
>
> It's worth noting that the `new` operator will also try and call an
>   init method in your CFC if you have one - although it doesn't need one
>   to work, other than that it works the same as:
>
> ```
>  createObject("component", "path.to.YourComponent")
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Who ever wrote this code to begin with didn't spend enough time to optimize it.

Comment: In CF9+ you can also use the `new` operator if you prefer like so: `<cfset comp = new path.to.YourComponent()>`. It's worth noting that the `new` operator will also try and call a `init` method in your CFC if you have one - although it doesn't need one to work, other than that it works the same as `createObject("component", "path.to.YourComponent")`

Comment: Depending on your setup, you might not even need a path to the component, just the name.

Comment: @JohnWhish  - Good point. I forgot that was introduced in 9 (was thinking 10). I will update the example.